# dragover vs dragenter events of HTML5 drag & drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I want to know the difference of `dragover` and `dragenter` events of HTML5 [drag &drop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API).

I'm not clear about the difference.

Comment: I think @ScaisEdge answer below should be accepted.

Answer (score 41):

The dragenter event happens at the moment you drag something in to the target element, and then it stops.
The dragover event happens during the time you are dragging something until you drop it.

Look here:

```
$('.dropzone').on("dragover", function (event) {
    console.log('dragover');
});
$('.dropzone').on("dragenter", function (event) {
    console.log('dragenter');
});
```

Now see the console:

[image]

As you can see the dragenter happen once (when you drag element in to the target).

But the dragover event ***happen every few hundred milliseconds***.

The same difference exist between drag and dragstart, dragstart happen once but drag ***happen every few hundred milliseconds***.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the [`dragenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragenter) and [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover) MDN doc...

**dragover**

> The dragover event is fired when an element or text selection is being
>   dragged over a valid drop target (**every few hundred milliseconds**).

**dragenter**

> The dragenter event is fired when a dragged element or text selection
>   enters a valid drop target.

The `dragover` is triggered after a small delay (every 350 ms, I think) while the cursor stays over the element.

Comment: Note that if you rerender the element while not moving the move (eg replace the element with a few one every few seconds), the dragenter event seems to be fired again.

Answer (score 1):

### [dragenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragenter_event):

`dragenter` event is fires only when while dragging an draggable element, the *cursor* **enters** the area of a DOM element which has the `ondragenter` event attached to it.

### [dragover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event):

On the other hand, `dragover` event is fired "constantly" while dragging a draggable element, and the cursor happens to be to be on the screen inside an DOM element's area, where this DOM element has the `ondragover` event attached to it.

---

> The difference is that (while dragging) when the cursor enters a drop-zone, `dragover` is constantly fired (on mouse move) while
> `dragenter` is only fired once, when the cursor has "entered"

## DEMO:

```js
function dragover(e) {
 console.log("drag over")
}

function dragenter(e) {
  console.log("drag enter!!!")
}
```

```css
#target{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid gold;
}

div[draggable]{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true">Drag Me</div>
<div id="target" ondragover="dragover(event)" ondragenter="dragenter(event)">Drop Zone</div>
```